# Override contrib module's template for an admin module

Tags: webforms, 9, theme-negotiation

I need to override a contrib module's template for an admin module. For example, the [webform_composite](https://drupal.org/webform_composite) module has `hook_theme()` in its module file.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function webform_composite_theme() {
  return [
    'webform_composite' => [
      'render element' => 'element',
    ],
  ];
}
```

and a template in its templates folder at

```
modules/contrib/webform_composite/templates/webform-composite.html.twig
```

Changes made to the template print on the webform. I don't want to make changes to the module's template and I don't want to make a sub-theme of the admin theme. I want to override the contrib module's template in my custom module.

In my custom module, `hook_theme()` is like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [       
    'webform_composite__custom' => [
      'base hook' => 'webform_composite',
    ],
  ];
}
```

And `hook_theme_suggestions_alter()` is like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_alter().
 */
function my_module_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
  if ($hook === 'webform_composite') {
    $suggestions[] = $hook . '--' . 'custom';
  }
}
```

as well as adding a template in modules/custom/my_module/templates/webform-composite--custom.html.twig

This adds my template but not as an override since `webform-composite.html.twig` still has the `x`.

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'webform_composite' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * webform-composite--my-award.html.twig
   * webform-composite--custom.html.twig
   x webform-composite.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'modules/contrib/webform_composite/templates/webform-composite.html.twig' -->
```

How do I override a contrib module's template for an admin module?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you override a module's template from another module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/313816/how-do-you-override-a-modules-template-from-another-module)

Comment: Might they also need to adjust the hook invocation order?

Comment: I updated my question with what I think are the right changes from your suggestions. But it's still reading the `webform-composite.html.twig` instead of my `webform-composite--custom.html.twig`.

Comment: Theme suggestions use underscore characters as delimiters; they are changed to hyphens only when Drupal core is searching for the template file.

Comment: Thanks @apaderno. Was just uncovering the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `'--'` to `__` in the $suggestions array fixed the problem per this core issue: [hook_theme_suggestions_alter does not work for hyphens](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2947868)

Here's the working code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'webform_composite__custom' => [
      'base hook' => 'webform_composite',
    ],
  ];
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_alter().
 */
function my_module_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
  if ($variables['theme_hook_original'] == "webform_composite") {
    $suggestions[] = $hook . '__' . 'custom';
  }
}
```

Now the debug reports:

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'webform_composite' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * webform-composite--my-award.html.twig
   x webform-composite--custom.html.twig
   * webform-composite.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'modules/custom/my_module/templates/webform-composite--custom.html.twig' -->
```

The first template suggestion is from webform_composite.module -> hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
The second template suggestion is my custom module.
The third template suggestion is from webform_composite.module -> hook_theme().

My custom template has the `x` and is the template read in by Drupal.